# How to wait for answer from user in telegrambotapi

Tags: python, bots, py-telegram-bot-api

Hello i am making rock paper scissors game in telegram and i have a problem with waiting for user input after i ask what they choose from the list of choices ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']. I am using PyTelegramBotApi

```
def hello(message):
    if message.text == '/info':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'daada :)')

    elif message.text == '/start':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello! My name is Anton and I am telegram bot')

    elif message.text == '/game':
        rock_paper_scissors(message)
```

this is how game is called

```
def rock_paper_scissors(message):

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '1 - Rock\n2 - Paper\n3 - Scissors')

    choice = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

    if answer.text.lower() not in choice:
        bot.send_message(answer.chat.id, 'Uknown choice!')
    else:
        bot.send_message(answer.chat.id, game(answer.text.lower()))
```

This is the game func
game fucn returns string: lose win draw
so i want to put user input in answer variable

Comment: pls put in the code

Comment: simpler idea: you could send answer directly in message `/game rock` and check if `message.text.startswith("/game")` and later split message to get second word `answer = message.text.split(" ")[1].lower()`

Comment: more complex idea: first set global variable `game_running = False`. When you get `/game` then set `game_running = True` and only display message with rules. And later `hello()` would have to check: if `game_running` is `True` and message doesn't start with `/` then send this as `answer` to `game()`. And after running `game()` you can set back `game_running = False` to stop game after one answer or `hello()`  can wait for message ie. `/end` to set `game_running = False` and stop game after many answers.

Comment: If many users may play at the same time then you may need to use dictionary `game_running[user_id] = False`